# Using installed SSL/TLS certificate with SoapUI?

Tags: web-services, certificate, ssl-certificate, soapui

I need to be able to hit a web service using SoapUI to inspect the request and response. I was previously provided with a certificate in the form of a .PFX file, along with the keystore password, which I could import into SoapUI and successfully hit the service.

The certificate I was provided recently expired, and my company has now deployed a new certificate via SCCM to my machine. I have the certificate installed in both Local Machine and Current User.

My question is:
**Is there a way to use an installed certificate (meaning I can't export it first) to complete the SSL/TLS handshake when making a request via SoapUI?**

Everything I've been able to find on the web has referenced exporting the certificate and setting the SSL settings in SoapUI (like I did before). Unfortunately, I do not have required authority to export the certificate to a .PFX file with a keystore password...

I assume there has to be a configuration setting of some sort in SoapUI that will let me hit the service with my installed certificate, but I can't find it for the life of me. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Even confirmation that it's impossible is appreciated; just not as much as I would appreciate a solution ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you can! Try this link a bit old but hopefuly could help http://geekswithblogs.net/gvdmaaden/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-configure-soapui-with-client-certificate-authentication.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment jtabuloc! However, as previously mentioned, I'm unable to export the certificate to PFX, nor am I able to export it with the private key. I need to be able to use SoapUI with an already installed certificate; not one that needs exported first.